# AngularJS - Can't display data from JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

First of all let me thank you for all the great job you guys are doing here.
You helped me a lot when having different bugs.
But this time nothing seems to fix my issues.
I'm trying to consume a JSON with Angular JS which I'm generating using Spring Boot.
**The JSON looks like this:**

```
{
  "id": 65,
  "url": "http://localhost:9000/",
  "key": "com.SocGen:Test",
  "name": "Test",
  "lname": "Test",
  "scope": "PRJ",
  "qualifier": "TRK",
  "uuid": "AVMtRdoEBufaCmDWZmPf",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "date": "2016-03-11T11:57:29+0200",
  "creationDate": "2016-02-29T15:44:25+0200",
  "allMsr": [
    {
      "id": 2855,
      "key": "files",
      "val": "10.0",
      "frmt_val": "10",
      "project": null,
      "date": "2016-03-11T11:57:29+0200"
    },
    {
      "id": 2856,
      "key": "duplicated_blocks",
      "val": "0.0",
      "frmt_val": "0",
      "project": null,
      "date": "2016-03-11T11:57:29+0200"
    }
  ]
}
```

My **index.html** looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="hello.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <table ng-controller="Hello">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>URL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{project.id}}</td>
            <td>{{project.name}}</td>
            <td>{{project.url}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And **hello.js**:

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/project/65').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.project = data;
        });
}
```

I spent like 2 hours trying to find a solution but no luck.
I know that this question has answers already but I tried alot of them and none of them seem to work for me.

So, what's the mistake here?
Thank you!

Comment: Is that all of `hello.js`?

Comment: is the json the same you use? because `"allMsr": [` starts an array, but it is never "closed".

Comment: @Starscream1984, yes! That's all of it!

Comment: Can you put a break point in your success handler function and verify that you actually get there, and if data is what you are expecting it to be?

Comment: @razpi, I fixed it. "allMsr" is way bigger but I deleted 90% of it because wasn't relevant. Forgot to put the "]" but now it's fixed.

Comment: Your code [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/45U2V5xTYp4IPS6uc5LW) Should do proper controller declaration though.

Comment: @charlietfl, You're right! It works! Thank you!

Comment: You neglected to provide error details that make all of this code irrelevant since it is server side CORS issue per other comments you made below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was running it locally and my browser had CORS (cross origin resource sharing) blocked.

The way to solving it was to install a little extension for chrome. Just search for it, and you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

As you said CORS blocked your request.

How can it be a solution to your problem to just add a chrome extension. It won't work on any other browser. Can you just ask the user to install a chrome extension to run your application.

Permanent solution would be adding the CORS header from the server side.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

Here are some links to go through your problem:

- [Link1](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipjJazsaLPAhVK4WMKHd31A7QQFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.html5rocks.com%2Fen%2Ftutorials%2Fcors%2F&usg=AFQjCNEqGW6hrCKA6tJWxPT0-r66XZGgeQ)
- [Link2](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)